# Why isn't there a Business Intelligence site?

Tags: discussion, area-51, site-proposal

Reports are back in the market! Business Intelligence is gaining market traction with products from Microsoft SSIS/SSRS, Oracle OBIEE, Microstrategy to QlikView.

Having a dedicated Q&A site for it may even get *industry giants'* or expert technical advisors attention/support to BI community. E.g. [Jon Skeet](http://tekpub.com/products/so_skeet) has been an active supporter to SO Java/C# community and SO as a whole reckon.

There's one for Database Admins. What about BI?
I checked on the [Business Tab](https://stackexchange.com/sites#business):

1. Project Management
2. Freelacing
3. Quantitative Finance
4. Bitcoin

Why isn't there a BI dedicated SO site? Is it too *costly*? or [Is the user base and valid BI questions asked in SO too low?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/business-intelligence)

How does SO decide which "area" of sites to be released?
Or being a dedicated site perhaps increases the risk of losing attention to a beta site?

Comment: Your why is because no one has proposed it. So go do it.

Comment: @animuson [Voila and appreciate all the support](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/70503/business-intelligence?referrer=EPHSm8-3avvaMxLjdRIeNg2)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If there isn't one it's because either no-one's proposed one or there hasn't been enough demand for one in the past. Head off to [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) and see if there isn't one already in definition.

If not, then propose it yourself.

Either way once there is a proposal go out and promote it where ever BI people hang out to try to get it through definition and commitment to the beta stage. Once there keep promoting it as well as asking good questions and providing excellent answers and you'll get the community.

"If you build it they will come"

Comment: I thought I knew SO... shame on me. BUT [there isn't any on BI yet though](http://area51.stackexchange.com/search?q=business+intelligence&page=1&returnTitle=Professional&returnUrl=%2fcategories%2f5%2fprofessional).

Comment: Entire StackExchange was on 'read-only' mode. So I am proposing now BI site under `Business` category. And you guys please support :D

Comment: [Here's BI Q&A initiative](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/70503/business-intelligence?referrer=EPHSm8-3avvaMxLjdRIeNg2)