# CRIFI.stackexchange.com

Tags: feature-request, site-proposal

There is ***scifi.stakexchange.com***.

I was wondering if we can have one on *crime* fiction and *mystery* with detective fiction so that we can discuss and answer questions more on Sherlock Holmes, Hercule Poirot and similar stuff.

It could be called

> crifi.stackexchange.com

based on crime fiction and mystery. This is based purely on **human intelligence** and within the world of **human reality**. It is quite different from fantasy, magic and thus away from SciFi or Movies & TV or Books. I hope somebody comes up with better activity.

I hope I have asked the right question on the right platform. If not suggest improvisation.

Comment: See my answer [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/232414/why-isnt-there-a-business-intelligence-site/232415#232415)

Comment: I had proposed a Mystery site on Area 51 some time ago, but it didn't get enough support so the proposal has disappeared. It takes more work than I put into it to get a proposal off the ground. I'd follow a new proposal, but someone would have to reach out to other mystery-loving communities on the 'net to generate enough interest.

Comment: @BilltheLizard I found 'Books'. Is it okay to start a topic within 'Books' on crime and mystery? I guess it is. So, we should start promoting 'Books'.

Comment: @MycrofD It looks like questions about mystery books will definitely be on-topic there. Unfortunately, that leaves out Movies and TV, but there's already [a site for that](http://movies.stackexchange.com/). I guess crime fiction/mystery questions will be split between the two sites.

Comment: @BilltheLizard yup. I had similar thoughts. It is splitting. Then perhaps a separate topic..separate site altogether. It deserves I guess.

Comment: It's probably worth another try. I'll support it, but it might be hard to get started since the Movies & TV site is already established. A lot of questions will naturally go there instead of to a new site.

Comment: yes. but still. we can have detective conan and other manga detective stuff. then sherlock and poirot and the list would gradually increase. this can be specifically devoted to crime and mystery. well let's see.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is actually a good questions, but it should start a bit further, namely **why** criminal stories are not on topic on SciFi, or why there's no single site for **any** fiction stories.

SciFi is not **only** about Science Fiction, but also about Fantasy. One can argue, that Science Fiction **is** a fairytale, where the magic was replaced by technology.

In many detective stories the main figure has overhuman intelligence, which **could** qualify it for fantasy... or not...

If the detective is portreted as an ordinary human, what does distinguish detective stories from **any other** fictive stories? Why separate site for **only** detective stories?

Why proposing a site for detective stories would make sense (it's what Area51 is for), I think it would make more sense for all fictive stories, maybe excluding explicite fantasy&scifi to not make folks from existing site jelous...

Personally, I think one site for any fantastic stories (books, comics, movies etc.) would do fine, but since we already get those separate sites, **Fictive Stories** proposal would be the best.

Comment: yes. you are quite right. Somebody with experience and expertise should take this actively.